# Invalid genesis file:cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Genesis.alloc of type *math.HexOrDecimal256

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs, genesis

Here is my genesis.json file

```
{
    "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "gasLimit": "21000000",
    "difficulty": "20000",
    "alloc": {
      "6e8f98fa53bbb9ab8dad40af34b767172206099f":{"balance":500000000}
     }
}
```

But I got the following error while `init` command in the genesis file

> Fatal: invalid genesis file: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go
>   struct field Genesis.alloc of type *math.HexOrDecimal256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balance quantities have to go as strings, because they are `big.Int` numbers and are parsed from a string as input. Strings are used because no 64bit integer capabale of holding amounts with 18 zeros. So change this:

```
"6e8f98fa53bbb9ab8dad40af34b767172206099f":{"balance":500000000}
```

to this:

```
"6e8f98fa53bbb9ab8dad40af34b767172206099f":{"balance":"500000000"}
```

Also, you allocated 500 pico Ethers, you won't be able to transfer 1 Ether in your tests. To allocate 1 Ether you would need to add 18 zeros in the balance.

Comment: Do you have answer for this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/insufficient-funds-for-gas-price-value-with-custom-gensis-json

Comment: @iambatman ,yeah, you allocated 500 picoethers and gas price is measured in Gweis, it is 3 zeros more.

Comment: I can't understand it

Comment: @iambatman , allocate a balance 500 + 18 zeros, and it is going to work.

Comment: You mean the gasLimit?

Comment: @iambatman, no, I mean , your account has not enough funds to send a transaction

Answer (score 0):

Try with this version

```
{
    "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "gasLimit": "21000000",
    "difficulty": "20000",
    "alloc": {
      "6e8f98fa53bbb9ab8dad40af34b767172206099f":{"balance":"500000000"}
     }
}
```

I just added quotation marks around the number `"500000000"`

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple jensis.json??

Comment: Why do you need multiple genesis blocks?